# How to remove multiple radio button selection for the same value -react

Tags: reactjs

I have same value repeated for say 3-4 times, if i select the first value the other related values are geeting selected
I dont want to select all the same values

ex:

```
const tuitions = [
{ value: 'ValueA', key: 'KeyA', name: 'Name A',timestamp:"2020-05-07T10:01:16.776+0000" },
{ value: 'ValueB', key: 'KeyB', name: 'Name B', timestamp:"2020-05-07T09:01:16.776+0000"  },
{ value: 'ValueC', key: 'KeyC', name: 'Name C' , timestamp:"2020-05-07T08:22:55.546+0000" },
{ value: 'ValueA', key: 'KeyA', name: 'Name A', timestamp:"2020-05-07T08:22:16.566+0000"  },
{ value: 'ValueA', key: 'KeyA', name: 'Name A', timestamp:"2020-05-07T08:01:16.77+0000"  },
];

const RadioButton = (props) => (
<label>
  <input 
    type="radio"
    name="Schools"
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.onChange}
  />
  {props.name}
</label>
);

class Thingy extends React.Component {
 _RadioClickHandler = (e, name) => {
  }
 render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {tuitions.map(item=>(
       <RadioButton 
         value={item.value} 
         key={item.key} 
         name={item.name} 
         onChange={e => this._RadioClickHandler (e, item.name) }  
       />
       )
     )}
  </div>
);
}
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
<Thingy />,
document.body
);
```

if i select Name A all the name A related stuff gets checked, how to avoid this.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but it seems it's doing exactly what you tell it to. Why are you using duplicate keys? This seems like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but it's perfectly working fine. Here is the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-http-ige4g

Comment: thanks but it not working with me.ya i saw it is working for you

Answer (score 0):

If you pass same value and select one of them all the other will be selected. That's how it works. You must need to pass unique value

## Updated

Suppose the display name is same but you should pass the value unique. If you need you can make them `ValueA1`  `ValueA2`  `ValueA3`